# Run a for loop in a variable

Tags: jquery, variables, for-loop

I was wondering, is it possible to run a for loop inside of a variable? I have a variable defined as `var table = $('<table border="1"><tr></tr>');` I would like to populate that first row with `<th>`s generated from an array. In theory, it would look something like:

```
var table = $('<table border="1"><tr>'for (var i=0; i< headers.length; i++){$("<th>"+headers[i]+"</th>")}'</tr>');
```

I have tried to run the for loop as

```
for (var i=0; i< headers.length; i++) {
    $("<th>"+headers[i]+"</th>").appendTo(table);
}
```

outside of the variable declaration, but because of other parts of the program, using `.appendTo` is not a viable solution.

Comment: can't you just iterate over your array building a string, and then use that string to create your table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you **really** can't do it outside of the variable declaration (which I don't see why you couldn't), how about something like this:

```
var headersString = '';  

for (var i=0; i < headers.length; i++) {  
    headersString += '<th>'+ headers[i] +'</th>';  
}  

('<table border="1"><tr>' + headersString + '</tr></table>');
```

Working example here: http://jsfiddle.net/hEKy5/

Answer (score 1):

Not really, but how about this

```
var row = $('table tr:first'); 
    for (var i=0; i < headers.length; i++)
       $("<th />").html(headers[i]).appendTo(row);
```

**EDIT**

I didn't realize attaching elements to the dom causes a page reflow.  This code will obviate that problem

```
var row = $('table tr:first').detach();
for (var i = 0; i < headers.length; i++)
    $("<th />").html(headers[i]).appendTo(row);
$("table").prepend(row);
```

Comment: Unfortunately this solution puts the `<th>`s at the bottom of the table as seen here: http://jsfiddle.net/Skooljester/UnBGw/1/

Comment: Use Prepend instead of Append?

Comment: @AdamTerlson - prepend could work, depending on the order his headers array is in.  But the script above should add th's to the first row.

Comment: @AdamRackis Hmm, that's interesting... I may need to go back and re-implement it then. Thank you very much!

Comment: @andrew - sure.  String concatenating is something I would try to avoid.  It's ugly and error prone.

Comment: @AdamRackis You want to avoid DOM manipulation within a loop. The correct way to do this would be to detach the TR element, add the cells to it via a loop, and then attach the TR element back to the DOM.

Comment: @AdamRackis Is there a better way to go about what I'm trying to do then? I don't have much experience and therefore am just trying  do things with the knowledge I do have.

Comment: @AdamRackis I see no reason that my string concatenating answer above is ugly or error prone. It looks just as concise as yours. Furthermore, apending every item of the array, one at a time, is extremely slow. Please look at the following article for more on the subject and also some performance measurements:
http://www.learningjquery.com/2009/03/43439-reasons-to-use-append-correctly

Comment: @Andrew - either answer should be fine.  If you have hundreds of th's to append, you would probably want to detach the node, add them en masse like Sime said, then re-attach.  If there's only a few however, then don't worry about it.  As Donald Knuth says, "premature optimization is the root of all evil"

Comment: @AdamRackis DOM manipulation triggers a page reflow (the position and dimensions of every element on the page are recalculated). You want to minimize the number of page reflows. It is not reasonable to add cells to a table in a way that triggers a page reflow after each added cell. So, it's not just performance, but common sense.